# Define Global Variable Fails in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-contacts

I am doing the Retrieve Contact Names tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html
I am able to import the following as called for:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
}
```

However, I get errors like

Error:(125, 9) error: class, interface, or enum expected

when I put the following code into the MainActivity.java file that is just supposed to be defining global variables and the build fails:

```
  /*
     * Defines an array that contains column names to move from
     * the Cursor to the ListView.
     */
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private final static String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    /*
     * Defines an array that contains resource ids for the layout views
     * that get the Cursor column contents. The id is pre-defined in
     * the Android framework, so it is prefaced with "android.R.id"
     */
    private final static int[] TO_IDS = {
           android.R.id.text1
    };
    // Define global mutable variables
    // Define a ListView object
    ListView mContactsList;
    // Define variables for the contact the user selects
    // The contact's _ID value
    long mContactId;
    // The contact's LOOKUP_KEY
    String mContactKey;
    // A content URI for the selected contact
    Uri mContactUri;
    // An adapter that binds the result Cursor to the ListView
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
```

How can this be fixed?

This is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In the above, when the variables were placed under the MainActivity, it leaves this one problem remaining with an invalid method error over this code:

```
    // Empty public constructor, required by the system
    public ContactsFragment() {}

    // A UI Fragment must inflate its View
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the fragment layout
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment,
                container, false);
    }
    class ContactsFragment extends Fragment implements
            LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        }

        /**
     * Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
     * been clicked.
     * <p>
     * Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need
     * to access the data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param parent   The AdapterView where the click happened.
     * @param view     The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this
     *                 will be a view provided by the adapter)
     * @param position The position of the view in the adapter.
     * @param id       The row id of the item that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

From here:

```
package com.google.firebase.codelab.friendlychat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.appinvite.AppInviteInvitation;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseAppIndex;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseUserActions;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.Indexable;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.builders.Actions;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.builders.Indexables;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.builders.PersonBuilder;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig;
import com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
/*
     * Defines an array that contains column names to move from
     * the Cursor to the ListView.
     */

 /*
     * Defines an array that contains column names to move from
     * the Cursor to the ListView.
     */
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private final static String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
        Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
        >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
    /*
     * Defines an array that contains resource ids for the layout views
     * that get the Cursor column contents. The id is pre-defined in
     * the Android framework, so it is prefaced with "android.R.id"
     */
private final static int[] TO_IDS = {
        android.R.id.text1
        };
        // Define global mutable variables
        // Define a ListView object
        ListView mContactsList;
        // Define variables for the contact the user selects
        // The contact's _ID value
        long mContactId;
        // The contact's LOOKUP_KEY
        String mContactKey;
        // A content URI for the selected contact
        Uri mContactUri;
// An adapter that binds the result Cursor to the ListView
private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;


    // Empty public constructor, required by the system
    public ContactsFragment() {}

    // A UI Fragment must inflate its View
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the fragment layout
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_fragment,
                container, false);
    }
    class ContactsFragment extends Fragment implements
            LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        }

        /**
     * Callback method to be invoked when an item in this AdapterView has
     * been clicked.
     * <p>
     * Implementers can call getItemAtPosition(position) if they need
     * to access the data associated with the selected item.
     *
     * @param parent   The AdapterView where the click happened.
     * @param view     The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this
     *                 will be a view provided by the adapter)
     * @param position The position of the view in the adapter.
     * @param id       The row id of the item that was clicked.
     */
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}




    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        return Actions.newView("Main", "http://friendlychat.firebase.google.com/message");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().start(getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().end(getIndexApiAction());
        super.onStop();
    }

    public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView messageTextView;
        public ImageView messageImageView;
        public TextView messengerTextView;
        public CircleImageView messengerImageView;

        public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            messageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            messageImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messageImageView);
            messengerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerTextView);
            messengerImageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.messengerImageView);
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    public static final String MESSAGES_CHILD = "messages";
    private static final int REQUEST_INVITE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 2;
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 10;
    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    private static final String MESSAGE_SENT_EVENT = "message_sent";
    private static final String MESSAGE_URL = "http://friendlychat.firebase.google.com/message/";
    private static final String LOADING_IMAGE_URL = "https://www.google.com/images/spin-32.gif";

    private String mUsername;
    private String mPhotoUrl;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

    private Button mSendButton;
    private RecyclerView mMessageRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
    private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private ImageView mAddMessageImageView;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
            // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        } else {
            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mMessageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messageRecyclerView);
        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder>(
                FriendlyMessage.class,
                R.layout.item_message,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)) {

            @Override
            protected FriendlyMessage parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = super.parseSnapshot(snapshot);
                if (friendlyMessage != null) {
                    friendlyMessage.setId(snapshot.getKey());
                }
                return friendlyMessage;
            }

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder,
                                              FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage, int position) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                if (friendlyMessage.getText() != null) {
                    viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
                    viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                } else {
                    String imageUrl = friendlyMessage.getImageUrl();
                    if (imageUrl.startsWith("gs://")) {
                        StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                .getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);
                        storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(
                                new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    String downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                                    Glide.with(viewHolder.messageImageView.getContext())
                                            .load(downloadUrl)
                                            .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);
                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Getting download url was not successful.",
                                            task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Glide.with(viewHolder.messageImageView.getContext())
                                .load(friendlyMessage.getImageUrl())
                                .into(viewHolder.messageImageView);
                    }
                    viewHolder.messageImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
                }


                viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
                if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                    viewHolder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,
                            R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_36dp));
                } else {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
                            .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                            .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
                }

                if (friendlyMessage.getText() != null) {
                    // write this message to the on-device index
                    FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(getMessageIndexable(friendlyMessage));
                }

                // log a view action on it
                FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().end(getMessageViewAction(friendlyMessage));
            }
        };

        mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the user is at the bottom of the list, scroll
                // to the bottom of the list to show the newly added message.
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                        (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) && lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    mMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });

        mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);

        // Initialize and request AdMob ad.
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Initialize Firebase Measurement.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

        // Initialize Firebase Remote Config.
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

        // Define Firebase Remote Config Settings.
        FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings firebaseRemoteConfigSettings =
                new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
                .setDeveloperModeEnabled(true)
                .build();

        // Define default config values. Defaults are used when fetched config values are not
        // available. Eg: if an error occurred fetching values from the server.
        Map<String, Object> defaultConfigMap = new HashMap<>();
        defaultConfigMap.put("friendly_msg_length", 10L);

        // Apply config settings and default values.
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(firebaseRemoteConfigSettings);
        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(defaultConfigMap);

        // Fetch remote config.
        fetchConfig();

        mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(mSharedPreferences
                .getInt(CodelabPreferences.FRIENDLY_MSG_LENGTH, DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT))});
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });

        mAddMessageImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addMessageImageView);
        mAddMessageImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername,
                        mPhotoUrl, null);
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
                mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(MESSAGE_SENT_EVENT, null);
            }
        });
    }

    private Action getMessageViewAction(FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage) {
        return new Action.Builder(Action.Builder.VIEW_ACTION)
                .setObject(friendlyMessage.getName(), MESSAGE_URL.concat(friendlyMessage.getId()))
                .setMetadata(new Action.Metadata.Builder().setUpload(false))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like in `MainActivity.java` you forgot to declare the class. Make sure that you defined the class properly like

```
public class MainActivity.java
```

Comment: The ContactsFragment as shown in the edited question seems to be stopping the code from compiling still. I'm still not sure how to implement that code so it will compile.